# Utilizing the dcm4che DICOM toolkit and dcm4chee archive (PACS) to implement cloud-based image sharing platform in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dcm4che

I am working with the dcm4chee archive to run the PACS server. I would like to upload images from my Node.js server to the PACS server to create a cloud-based image hosting platform. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem. The PACS server seems pretty complicated for me to understand as Javascript developer so any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you need to first understand the concept of Dicom Wado (Chapter 18 of the Standard). Now you need to implement a solution to send DICOM images generated by the medical form to a "Cloud PACS", in this case your application.

As "best practices" in managing medical images, should not be used as FTP services for sending and receiving images. This should be managed within an encrypted private network such as a VPN using the Dicom protocols.

Must consider whether the Cloud PACS solution can be "integrated" into a VPN or need some kind of Dicom Router. You can review applications running as servers, such as:

- Conquest Dicom Server
- Orthanc Dicom Server
- Mirth Connect